# Curses addstr() variable instead of integer causes error?

Tags: python, curses

I've started working on a curses program in python and I have come across this issue. The code "logo.addstr(count, 1, line)" gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intro.py", line 90, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/curses/__init__.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "intro.py", line 22, in main
    show_rank_logo()
  File "intro.py", line 87, in show_rank_logo
    logo.addstr(count, 1, line)
_curses.error: addwstr() returned ERR
```

If you replace "count" with 1, the lines will show up but on one line (as it should). This file is ASCII art so I want it to display in the window (named logo) all at once. This is why I added a count to the loop. But the variable which equals 1 somehow gives an error.

```
 def show_rank_logo():
     logo = curses.newwin(35, 105, 1, 51)
     logo.box()
     count = 1
     with open('platinum_logo.txt') as file:
         for line in file.readlines():
             logo.addstr(count, 1, line)
             count += 1
             logo.refresh()
```

Looking for any help!

Comment: I would guess that the problem didn't occur when `count` was 1, as you seem to assume, but rather on some later iteration of the loop when `count` exceeded the height of your window.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks. I added a limit of lines to print and it worked.